# EBean PlayFramework 2.2.x It has not been enhanced but it's superClass [class play.db.ebean.Model] is?

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.2, ebean

I have started getting these errors but only when I do a stage.
If I start play in console mode its fine.

The error I get is random sometimes its one class sometime its another.

```
2015-04-08 17:11:14 345 - [ERROR] - from 

com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.deploy.BeanDescriptorManager in main
Error in deployment
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Error with [model.ExpenseReportHistory] It has not been enhanced but it's superClass [class play.db.ebean.Model] is? (You are not allowed to mix enhancement in a single inheritance hierarchy) marker[play.db.ebean.Model] className[model.ExpenseReportHistory]
        at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.deploy.BeanDescriptorManager.setEntityBeanClass(BeanDescriptorManager.java:1445) ~[org.avaje.ebeanorm.avaje-ebeanorm-3.2.2.jar:na
```

I can normally overcome these errors but this one has me stumped. 
One thing to note is that all the getters and setters are created by myself so I am not sure if the EBean orm enhancer doesn't like them.

What I would like to know is how to get some more information on how to track down the exact issue. The class that its complaining looks fine. It has private members with public getters and setters. A default constructor.

It is also worth noting that all my unit tests run and these include database tests. 
Could it be that on stage the enhancer is somehow no longer available?

Comment: Are you compiling the ExpenseReportHistory apart from the main Play project and including it as a subproject?  Or are you specifying a different config file during the stage task?  If so, are you specifying the models in that config like ebean.default="models.*"?

Comment: Everything is compiled at the same time with the same property file. This is my configuration for the ebean models.
ebean.default="model.*,model.audit.*, model.email.*,model.notification.*,model.payment.*,model.referral.*,model.user.*,"

Comment: You should only need the one "model.*" entry, as I believe that Play's model enhancer searches the sub directories recursively.  How did you end up calling out all of those subdirectories explicitly?

Comment: I always had it as the single model.* but changed it on various forum recommendations. It made no difference

Comment: Could you post your build.sbt or Build.scala file please?  Also, do you run "play clean stage" or just "play stage"?  I only use public fields without customized getter/setters, so I may not be of too much help, sorry...

Comment: The strange thing is that if I do an "activator clean" then "activator" to bring up the play command. I then debug and it runs fine. When I stage I always do a clean before doing a stage. I wish I had not added in the setters and getters but with my java hat on it felt wrong. But I think its this that is causing the issue with the enhancement

Answer (score 1):

I finally resolved the issue. 
To recap I could build and run fine in dynamic mode but not if I did and activator stage.

The reason was that the application.conf which had all the dev config had the db config taken out and put in two individual property files. 
E.g dev1.conf and dev2.conf which each did an include of the application.conf

Unfortunately the solution was to create two full properties files dev1.conf and dev2.conf each with all of application.conf